# How to single out which Java class definition is missing/which dependencies to import?

Tags: java, http, intellij-idea

Though I understand OOP, I'm very new to Java's way of implementing external libraries. I am currently just trying to mess around with HTTP requests to the IEX trading API, as shown in the Java option here https://rapidapi.com/eec19846/api/investors-exchange-iex-trading.
Just to get started, I tried to run that code exactly in IntelliJ:

```
package com.company;

import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse; //

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.get("https://investors-exchange-iex-trading.p.rapidapi.com/stock/msft/effective-spread")
                    .header("x-rapidapi-host", "investors-exchange-iex-trading.p.rapidapi.com")
                    .header("x-rapidapi-key", "(my_key_here)")
                    .asString();
            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And I am already getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequest
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asString(BaseRequest.java:56)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpRequest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 38 more
```

I included all the necessary dependencies (org.json, httpclient_4.3.6, httpmime_4.3.6, httpasyncclient_4.0.2) in the project's classpath, and I'm really not sure how to interpret this error. The reference to Main.java:16 in the error message is the line with ".asString()".

Anybody know what's going on here? How can I approach finding the missing classdef in this situation?

Comment: You put it into Google and you find that you're missing httpcore?

Comment: *"I included all the necessary dependencies (org.json, httpclient_4.3.6, httpmime_4.3.6, httpasyncclient_4.0.2) in the project's classpath"* --- Why do you believe those are *all* the necessary dependencies? Where did you get that list? Did you check transitive dependencies too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failure is due to the runtime dependency on `org.apache.http.HttpRequest`.

Whenever there is a class not found exception I would start with finding in which library that class exists. The `org.apache.http.HttpRequest` class is in the [httpcore library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore).

If you're using Maven you can look at the POM dependency graph to see if httpcore is there and if it is, running build with dependencies should pick that library up.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it would be something obvious like that, though I would've expected more similarity between the names of the .jar files and the packages themselves as I would not have known that httpcore was the library needed.

Answer (score 0):

The error is indeed that the class org.apache.http.HttpRequest can't be found. In most situations the IDE (IntelliJ) can find the class or know in which non project jar it can be found. 
If the IDE didn't give a popup/suggestion to define the correct import or to add a dependency, the best think you can help is by putting the filename "org.apache.http.HttpRequest" into a search engine like Google search. That will give you enough information which library you have to add on your classpath (and in your POM for example).

The current missing artifact (Jar file) is:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.13

Comment: Thank you! That answers my question--I will do that now whenever I don't know which library a class is from.